# nginx.conf (permission to write denied). How do I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx

So I am trying to follow the tutorial here: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04 to deploy a Rails app. When I tried to edit the nginx.conf at (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) file, it tells me I have read only permission, even though I followed the steps(with setting the permissions) previously. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you need sudo to edit that file, because it's owned by root user,

use `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or `sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` which ever editor you prefer.